# My plane in blender is invisible. Why?

Tags: solidify-modifier

I am trying to make a 3d Model with a plane in Blender, but it only shows the outlines on the outside of it:
[image]

It has the Solidify mod on it, but that was an attempt to get it to turn visible, and it didn't work.
Why?

Comment: Hello, as Laserlas says, please share your file

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might have changed the viewport shading to *Wireframe* accidentally (maybe you pressed **Shift+Z**?). There's a menu in the upper right corner of the 3D View. Try to select one of the other options:

[image]

If this doesn't help, you might want to upload your Blend File here, so we can have a closer look: https://blend-exchange.com/